# Получить аватарку контакта из телефонной книги

Tags: android, java

Добрый вечер.

Возник следующий вопрос.

Я получаю список всех вызовов пользователя устройства, то есть журнал(**CallLog**) следующим образом:

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        sb.append("Call Details :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            String callName = managedCursor.getString(name);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        }
```

По документации для получения автарки необходим CONTACT_ID. Как его получить либо сразу аватарку контакта?

Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если известен CONTACT_ID:

```
Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
           ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
InputStream photoStream = ContactsContract.Contacts
           .openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photoStream,
            null, options);
```

Если **CONTACT_ID** неизвестен, то его можно найти, например, по номеру телефона:

```
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
    Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
    Cursor c = cr.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
    }
```

Также стоит учитывать, что номер телефона может быть записан несколько раз под разными именами.